# rails new blog failing to install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs, railstutorial.org

I'm following a tutorial to set up a simple Ruby on Rails blog but when I enter "rails new blog" I get the following error. 
Does anyone know what the problem is? I have no experience using Rails and just recently started learning Ruby, and help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Ruby Version: ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x64-mingw32]
Rails Version: Rails 5.2.3
OS: Windows 10 64 bit

I've tried the advice in the command prompt, running the line:

```
gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0' -- source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

But I get this error:

```
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out
```

Error After intiially running : rails new blog

```
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  sqlite3
```

This is what's inside the gem_make.out file

```
current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0/ext/sqlite3
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20190424-3264-12r4lo3.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... yes
checking for -ldl... no
checking for dlopen()... no
missing function dlopen
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-sqlcipher
    --without-sqlcipher
    --with-sqlite3-config
    --without-sqlite3-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-sqlcipher
    --without-sqlcipher
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --with-dllib
    --without-dllib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Gemfile

replace `gem 'sqlite3'` to

```
gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"
```

Answer (score 1):

Will you try this gem?
It probably has to figure it out.

```
gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"
```